# Issue with consign and express paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, consign

I'm currently working on some university coursework, which is essentially an API written in express. We're allowed to use other packages as long as we follow the spec.

I'm trying to use [consign](https://www.npmjs.com/package/consign) for autoloading my models, middleware and routes. The problem I'm facing is the folder structure that we have to follow.

```
coursework
|-- artifact
|   |-- server
|   |   |-- api
|   |   |   |-- models
|   |   |   |   `-- stories.js
|   |   |   |-- middleware
|   |   |   |   `-- stories.js
|   |   |   `-- routers
|   |   |       `-- stories.js
|   |   |-- node_modules
|   |   |-- package.json
|   |   |-- package-lock.json
|   |   `-- server.js
|   `-- utilities
|-- node_modules
|-- webpages
|-- package.json
|-- package-lock.json
`-- test.js
```

Inside of `artifact` is where all of our code goes, nothing else is touched. The root directory that contains `test.js` is where we will be assessed. From the root we run `npm test` (QUnit) and then it lists which tests have passed and which have failed.

The problem is we have to start our server from the root directory by calling `node artifact/server` which is fine because it calls `artifact/server/server.js`.

Inside of **`artifact/server/server.js`** I have the following code to initialise **`consign`**:

```
consign({ cwd: './artifact/server/api' })
    .include('models')
    .then('middleware')
    .then('routers')
    .into(app);
```

When I run `node artifact/server` from the **root** directory I get the following error:

[image: Consign error]

What's frustrating is if I change consign's **`cwd`** property to `api` and then start the server inside of `artifact/server` by calling `node server.js` it works perfectly fine.

The problem is I need to be able to start the server from the root directory. I'm completely stuck as I do not know how I can modify consign to work from the root directory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my problem and felt that I should post an answer to help others.

Essentially, as shown above I was using a relative path like so:

```
consign({ cwd: './artifact/server/api' })
    .include('models')
    .then('middleware')
    .then('routers')
    .into(app);
```

which when called from the root directory resulted in consign not working. This can be fixed by making use of **`path`**

I added this at the top of my **`server.js`** file:

```
const path = require('path');
```

and then changed my **consign** init to:

```
consign({ cwd: path.join(__dirname, 'api') })
    .include('models')
    .then('middleware')
    .then('routers')
    .into(app);
```

This then fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue and getting this error

```
! Entity not found
```

...but then read [Node's path documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/path.html) and tried the following:

```
consign({
  cwd: path.dirname(__dirname)
})
```

Seems to be a solution if you need the working directory `cwd:` to be root `'./'`